# Get words separated by space from string

Tags: php

I have a variable, lets say

```
$var = "name1 field2_name name3 name4";
```

i need them to be in an array separately like this

```
$arr = array ('name1', 'field2_name', 'name3', 'name4');
```

so i can echo words in separate like this

```
echo $arr[0]; //echoes name1
```

Comment: Look up [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). An awful name, but it returns "an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter." Most other languages call this operation "split".

Comment: As an alternative to the obvious explode(), you could use str_word_count() with a custom character set to include numbers and underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the php explode function

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$arr = explode(' ', $var);
```